# php slim duplicate response body data

Tags: php, api, apache2, slim

I created a PHP API using Slim framework. The issue is when I moved the API to a new server I started getting issue with the response. The data in the response body is getting duplicated!

For example instead of getting this once in the response:

> {data: [{ username: 'someone', password: 'something' }] }

I'm getting this:

> {data: [{ username: 'someone', password: 'something' }] } 
>  
>   {data: [{ username: 'someone', password: 'something' }] }
>  
>   {data: [{ username: 'someone', password: 'something' }] }

It's happening on every response to any route.
Even the page not found it display twice.

here's whats in my .htaccess:

> RewriteEngine On 
>  RewriteBase / 
>  RewriteCond
>   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
>  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slim Framework Rest service getting output twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743249/slim-framework-rest-service-getting-output-twice)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had my index.php file added inside my routes folder as well by mistake. 
This might as well occur if you had multiple $app->run();

[Slim Framework Rest service getting output twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743249/slim-framework-rest-service-getting-output-twice)